# Math operations on values from files - Python

Tags: python, file

I would like to do math operations on files. I created threetxt files (prices, warehouse, raport)
I would like to save (price * quantity) of the product to raport.txt

It will be line1 from price * line1 from quantity.
I have no idea how to do this, I just opened files and saved values to the raports.

```
with open('prices.txt','r') as c:
with open('warehouse.txt','r') as s:
    with open('raport.txt', 'w') as r:
        for line in c:
            r.write(line)
        for line in s:
            r.write(line)
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation, make this code a [mre], explain your expected input versus expected output, and also explain why you were unable to find an existing solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data from the input files and then `zip` it together to produce the output file:

```
with open('prices.txt') as f:
    prices = [float(p) for p in f]
with open('warehouse.txt') as f:
    quantities = [int(q) for q in f]

with open('raport.txt', 'w') as f:
    for p, q in zip(prices, quantities):
        f.write(f"{p * q}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load, do the math and save to text file neatly with numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

prices = np.loadtxt('prices.txt', dtype=float)
quantities = np.loadtxt('warehouse.txt', dtype=float)

np.savetxt("rapport.txt", prices * quantities)
```